# refactor code to a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Currently I have

```
    <b>Step 1</b>    
      <%= @recipe_records.instruct_1 %>
     </p>   
    <p> 
    <b>Step 2</b>       
      <%= @recipe_records.instruct_2 %>
      </p>
    .....
    <b>Step 30</b>      
      <%= @recipe_records.instruct_30 %>
      </p>
```

How do I put it in a loop instead of listing all 30 steps and to not display empty steps?

```
    <% 30.times do |n|%>
        <% ri = @recipe_records.instruct_#{n+1}%>
        <%= if !ri.empty? %>
            <p>
            <%= ri %>
        <% end%>
    <% end %>
```

Tried but unable to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fidling, I've got the following working codes:

```
<% 30.times do |n|%>
    <% ri = @recipes.send("instruct#{n+1}")%>
    <% unless ri.blank? %>
        <p>
        <b><%= "Step #{n+1}"%></b>
        <%= ri %>
        <p/>
    <% end%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<% 30.times do |n|%>
    <% ri = @recipe_records.send("instruct_#{n+1}")%>
    <%= unless ri.empty? %>
        <p/>
        <%= ri %>
    <% end%>
<% end %>
```

For the record, I disagree with your accessor method names.. You should be accessing the entries in an array fashion and not have an accessor for each one.  For example @recipe_records[3] instead of @recipe_records_3

Comment: Hi, the code still gives me error, SyntaxError. `code`er.append= ( unless ri.empty? );@output_buffer.safe_concat('`code` For info, the .instruct_1 to .instruct_30 are columns in my db. Not sure im doing this in the correct method as im still quite new to RoR.